# Python Pandas (Excel) datasheet code issue

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have imported an excel (.xlsx) spreadsheet into my python code (using Pandas) and want to extract data from it and the spreadsheet contains the following;

```
DATE:        Lecture1:   Lecture2:
16/07/2020   09:30       11:00
17/07/2020   09:45       11:30
18/07/2020   09:45       11:00
19/07/2020   10:00       14:30
20/07/2020   09:30       14:45
```

How can I create the part of the code so that if "now = date.today()", then "print" the row of my lectures for that day...

I have the following;

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'/home/timetable1.xlsx')
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"]).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

This prints out the whole timetable as shown below (note the format changes slightly);

```
         Date  Lecture1  Lecture2
0  16-07-2020  09:30:00  11:00:00
1  17-07-2020  09:45:00  11:30:00
2  18-07-2020  09:45:00  11:00:00
3  19-07-2020  10:00:00  14:30:00
4  20-07-2020  09:30:00  14:45:00
```

So I am not sure what the part of the code will be to determine 'todays' date and show only 'todays' lecture times for example something like this maybe;

```
now = date.today()
now.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
if ["Date" == now]:
    print ('timetable1.xlsx' index_col=now)
```

I am new to coding so not very good at it. The above code is wrong I know I can't think of a way to display the info.

So my desired output that I want;

```
      Date  Lecture1  Lecture2
18-07-2020  09:45:00  11:00:00
```

Your input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Everything is correct except the last if statement. As you want to check the condtion in Dateframe, you need to either run a loop through it or use condition statement using pandas. I would prefer the later as it is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date']).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
now = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
print(data[data['Date'] == now])
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you Abhay. I do get the required output. Is there a way to make index column 0 as the main and get rid of the numbers that appear at the side? I tried the following but I get an error;          data = pd.read_excel(r'/home/timetable1.xlsx', index_col=0)

Comment: You can reset index using reset_index(), and if you want to remove the index then use reset_index(drop=true). Check this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: If you want to add the index to the dataframe column then you can use df['index'] = df.index and later use df.reset_index(drop=True) to remove it from the side. However I do not see the need to do this as you can access any row with index number without add it as column.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have entered the following but I receive an error; df['index'] = df.index       df.reset_index(drop=True) and doesnt work. The only way it works partially is if I do the following; df = pd.read_excel (r'/home/timetable1.xlsx', index_col=0, header=0)
print (df)   But then I cant add the other commands for the date==now etc everytime I add it , it errors out

Comment: Reason why I need that off is because I will use PyQT to use it as a label to display on a GUI interface. So just want to hide that part.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
from datetime import date
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE, format='%d/%m/%Y')
print(df[df.DATE == pd.to_datetime(date.today())])
```

Output (It's 19th for me)

```
        DATE Lecture1 Lecture2
3 2020-07-19    10:00    14:30
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is take in the current date in the correct format as the dataset like this:

```
today=date.today()
compare=today.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
```

And the do a .loc command on the dataframe

```
df.loc[df['Date'] == compare]
```